# Lost binding array when page refresh

Tags: angular8

I am trying to store date from input in array and then display all data in list every time user click save. But the problem is the displayed data reset when page refresh and I want to save it.

HTML code

```
<form class="list__form">
    <input type="text" name="items" [(ngModel)]="items" placeholder="What Do Yo Want To Do..!">
    <button (click)="addToList()">Save</button>
</form>
<ul *ngFor="let item of listItem">
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

The ts code

```
  items: string;
  listItem = [];

  addToList() {
    this.listItem.push(this.items);
    this.items = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page (refresh browser) all data in memory is lost. If you want to preserve that list in between page refresh you have to store it somewhere. One way to do it is store it in the local (browser) storage:

```
items: string;
listItem = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.listitem = this.getFromStorage('myItemList') || this.listItem;
}

addToList() {
   this.listItem.push(this.items);
    this.items = '';
   this.saveToStorage('myItemList', this.listItem);
}
```

#### Storing the list in the session storage, until the browser/tab is closed:

```
saveToStorage(key, value) {
   sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

getFromStorage(key) {
   sessionStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

#### Storing the list in the local storage, persisted until removed from storage:

```
saveToStorage(key, value) {
   localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

getFromStorage(key) {
   localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```